# Facebook Graph Api send message to users commenting posts

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm working on a backend application that uses FB Graph Api (v9.0) to create new posts on a page, get reactions and get comments.

Using Graph Api, is it possible to send a message to a user that left a comment or a reaction to one of my posts?

This is the basic workflow I implemented:

- step 1 - create new post on a page

```json
POST https://graph.facebook.com/{{page_id}}/feed?access_token={{page_token}}
{
    "message": "Lorem ipsum...",
}
```

which returns a {{post_id}}

- step 2 - read comments on the previous post

```json
GET https://graph.facebook.com/{{post_id}}/comments?access_token={{page_token}}&fields=id,from,created_time,message
```

which returns something like this

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "123456789012345_123456789012345",
      "created_time": "2021-02-10T13:13:40+00:00",
      "message": "some comment",
      "from": {
        "name": "some Facebook user",
        "id": "123456789012345"
      }
    }
  ],
...
}
```

- step 3 
  Now, via Graph Api, I wish to send a message to the user that left the comment, either private or public. For example giving some feedback to the commenter or asking some further informations. 
  The only attributes I managed to retrieve so far are **from.name** and **from.id**

Comment: Hi Roberto, thank you for your question. Can you provide more information about your implementation? Perhaps some code you have tried? As it is, your question is very broad and you may find answers to be opinionated, or simply a "yes" or "no" answer if we don't imply what you actually want to know :).

Comment: For comments, yes, that is called [private replies](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/private-replies). For mere reactions – nope, that would be way to intrusive & spammy.

Comment: @ConnorLow I added some details in my original question, thanks for your reply.

Comment: @CBroe many thanks! I will read the docs and give a try